# Assigning objects to a temp variable

Tags: javascript, performance

If you create objects like this:

```
building[45] = new Object();        
building[45].name = myName; 
building[45].price = parseInt(myPrice);

building[128] = new Object();       
building[128].name = myName;    
building[128].price = parseInt(myPrice);
```

Now if i wanted to use `building[128]` in a function is it better to assign it to a temporary variable so that the browser doesn't have to iterate through all the objects to find `building[128]` properties?

Example:

```
var theID = 128;
var temp = building[theID]; //temp.name & temp.price
```

Or just use `building[theID].name` and `building[theID].price` directly?

Is there any difference in how they are looked up ?

Comment: no there is no difference

Comment: @theshadowmonkey Could you provide support for that? (I'm just curious too but want some sort of proof)

Comment: Same i want to know the technical info on how the data is looked up in memory etc

Comment: Always use parseInt(whatev, 10). Too many silly mistakes happen with that second parameter missing. I really wish it were required.

Comment: @Dave is tehre a way in your program you get to know the number 128? If so accessing it building[theId] or using temp is the same. And I think my answer concerns something completely different. Removing it :)

Comment: No its not known its based on user selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array access is a constant time operation (in Big-O notation, this is `O(1)`). In other words, the browser does *not* need to iterate over 127 items before accessing `building[128]`.

That being the case, I would still recommend storing the array item in a variable. The chief reason for doing so is that JavaScript minification programs will be able to rename the variable to something short like `a`, so that property access is `a.name` and so on. This saves a few bytes here and there and on a larger scale the total byte savings are significant.

> JavaScript arrays are a specialized form of JavaScript object, and array indexes are really little more than property names that happen to be integers.
>   [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, David Flanagan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596000480)

Using Flanagan's definition of an array, each time you access an array item by its index, you are effectively starting a two-step process: access the array object, then look up the value by property name (index). By saving the array item in a variable, accessing it is as easy as looking at the value in memory.

Comment: So `building[128]` is a pointer in the same way a temporary var would be ?

Comment: I contradict with the first part because iterating the array is also O(1)

Comment: @theshadowmonkey uh... no, iterating over an array is pretty much the definition of O(N)

Comment: @ben336 sorry was a little confused. I wonder time complexity matters here because even when assigning the value to temp var, the value is iterated.

Comment: Dave, added additional information about how array access works to help answer your pointer question.

@theshadowmonkey, I only mentioned complexity because the OP made an incorrect assumption about how array access works. So the short answer is that it doesn't matter, as both methods are effectively equivalent in terms of time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can build like this:

```
building[45] = {
    name: myName,
    price: parseInt(myPrice, 10)
};

building[128] = {
    name: myName,
    price: parseInt(myPrice, 10)
};
```

**edit**: Oh, I see your question is different than how I read it. Sorry. I'll keep this answer here because it may be helpful.